# Type of auto reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

If I have the following two loops:

```
std::vector<int> v;

for(auto i : v)
  //do something with i

for(auto& j : v)
  //do something with j
```

When I hover over `i`, intellisense shows it as `int i` (as expected). However, when I hover over `j` I don't get `int&` as I expected to, but rather

```
std::_Simple_types<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Alloc>::value_type>::value_type &j
```

What is this complicated definition? Is it the same as `int&`? If not, what is it? And if it is, why can it deduce just `int` for `i`, but not `int&` for `j`?

Comment: What type does the *standard* say that `j` has to be? Surely it must be `int&` (or something `typedef`ed to an `int&`) to allow write-back to the original vector?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard states in `6.5.4 [stmt.ranges]`:

> For a range-based for statement of the form
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
> ```
>
> let `range-init` be equivalent to the expression surrounded by
>   parentheses
>
> ```
> ( expression )
> ```
>
> In each case, a range-based for statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto && __range = range-init;
>     for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,  __end = end-expr;  __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

So you can see that in your case the types of `i` and `j` are deduced from the type of `*it` where `it` is a `std::vector` iterator. `std::vector` iterators are implementation defined, however the result of `*it` is not.

---

As indicated in the comments, a `std::vector` iterator is a forward iterator, and after `24.2.5/1 [forward.iterators]`:

> A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward
>   iterator if
>
> - ...
> - if X is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,

Here `reference` is used in `24.4.4/2 [iterator.iterators]` to indicate the return type of `*it`.

---

Thus for your case  the standard requires the type of `i` to be `int` and the type of `j` to be `int&`. This is probably the case for MSVC++, and intellisense is just not able to correctly resolve the type.

---

**Edit:** Fixed the answer regarding the return type when dereferencing iterators.

Comment: No, that type is `int`, it is just a complex `typedef` to it.  `*it` for `vector` **must** be `T&` outside of the specialization `bool`.

Comment: @Yakk: Please give me a reference in the standard.

Comment: @Danvil C++11 24.2.5 Forward Iterator requirements paragraph 1: "if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a `const` iterator, `reference` is a reference
to `const T`, ..."

Comment: @Danvil 24.2.5 Forward Iterators -- `reference` is a reference to `T`.  24.2 Iterators -- `*a` returns `reference`.  Random access iterators are forward iterators, and `vector`'s iterators are random access iterators (barring `bool`, that evil specialization).  For more, we have 23.3.6.1/2: `reference` is `value_type&` and 23.2.3/16 (table 101) has `v.front()` returning `reference` and equivalent to `*a.begin()`. (a different `reference`, but `std::vector<T>::reference` is `T&` for non-`bool` `T`, I can find that if you care)

Comment: Ok, will adapt the answer.

Answer (score 8):

IntelliSense is giving you a peek into the implementation of `std::vector`. That is a complicated way of saying reference to `std::vector<int>::value_type` or, in this case, reference to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is `int`.  All that means is intellisense got confused and gave up.

Intellisense is not perfect: you can even get it to red squiggly compiling code.

Comment: In this case however intellisense is probably correct, it's just that the type is a `typedef` to int.

Comment: Yeah, best to turn off the red squiggles. C++ can be hard enough as it is without being given a glimpse into how hard Microsoft find it!

Comment: @Poldie Actually, since VS2010, Intellisense has been powered by an EDG front-end. So it's probably more capable than the VC compiler's front-end, but has features disabled so that they match those of the VC version it ships with.

Comment: @praetorian I have code that always squiggles at me: maybe they turned off too much, but it is not that hard to confuse with SFINAE style functions.

Comment: Did you actually mean "yes, it is `int&`"?

Comment: @Danvil `std::_Simple_types<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Alloc>::value_type>::value_type` is `int`, `std::_Simple_types<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Alloc>::value_type>::value_type&` is `int&`.

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering which of OPs question you are answering with that sentence.